# SpringBoot Unable to load Property file from Runnable jar due to multiple exclamation mark

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I have a Spring Boot project and everything works fine locally. Now when i create a runnable jar to run it via jenkins then it is not able to load Property file.
Following is the code where PropertyPlaceholder is configured:

```
@Bean
    public static EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurerEncrypted() {
        String env = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") != null ? System.getProperty("spring.profiles" +
                ".active") : "ci";
        EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc =
                new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(getStandardPBEStringEncryptor());
        ppc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"),
                new ClassPathResource("application-" + env + ".properties"));
        return ppc;
    }
```

In order to debug i added following code within this:

```
try {
            String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(new ClassPathResource("application-" + env + ".properties").getFile().toPath()));
            LOG.info(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to read file",e);
        }
```

And it gives this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-qa1.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/hudson/workspace/pv/target/T-S-21.3.40.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application-qa1.properties
17:23:44    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
```

I have confirmed that file is located in jar at this location `BOOT-INF/classes/application-qa1.properties`

So effectively issue is caused due to second exclamation mark showing up in path while loading file from jar `/var/hudson/workspace/pv/target/T-S-21.3.40.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application-qa1.properties`

Ideally exclamation mark should appear only after jar name.

Can someone please advise on how to address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read files from a JAR like this. You have to use getResourceAsStream like this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application-" + env + ".properties");
```